# How to make a grid without using Tables, Flexbox or a Grid-system

Tags: html, css, css-float, css-position

As you can see in the title I want to make a grid without using Tables, Flexbox or a Grid-system. But float can be used.
It should look like this(the exact colours don't care):

[image: How it should look]

I've looked for a similar topic but didn't found anything, which can help me.

What have I to change, that it looks like the picture above?
Thats my current code:

```css
/* ########################################################################## */
/* Global Settings */
/* ########################################################################## */

html, body{
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* ########################################################################## */
/* Clearfix-Hack */
/* ########################################################################## */

.clearfix::after{
 content:"";
 clear:both;
 display: block;
}

/* ########################################################################## */
/* Entire Page */
/* ########################################################################## */

.entire-page{
  margin: 0 15%;
}


/* ########################################################################## */
/* Square/Rectangle */
/*  ########################################################################## */

.square,
.div{
  width: calc((100% - 60px) / 3);
  float: left;
}

.div{
  height:422px;
}

.rectangle {
  width: calc((100% - 60px) / 3 * 2 + 30px);
  float: left;
}

.row{
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.row .square:nth-of-type(1) {
 margin-right: 30px;
}

.row .square:nth-of-type(3) {
 margin-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="src/css/styles4.css">
</head>

<body>

  <!-- ########################################################################## -->
  <!-- Entire Page -->
  <!-- ########################################################################## -->
  <div class="entire-page">

        <!-- ########################################################################## -->
        <!-- Square/Rectangle  -->
        <!--  ########################################################################## -->

        <section>
            <div>

              <div class="row row-1">
                <div class="square pic1"><img src="https://www1.xup.in/exec/ximg.php?fid=56589964"></div>
                <div class="square pic1"><img src="https://www1.xup.in/exec/ximg.php?fid=56589964"></div>
                <div class="square div"></div>
              </div>

              <div class="row row-2">
                <div class="rectangle pic2"><img src="https://www1.xup.in/exec/ximg.php?fid=19960346"></div>
                <div class="square div"></div>
              </div>

            </div>
        </section>

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use .  There are 2 rows - i.e., `<tr>'s`.  The 1st row has 3 columns - i.e., `<td>'s.`  The 2nd row only has 2 `<td>'s`, and the 1st one on that row has a colspan=2.

Read more about tables [here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp).

Apply styles as desired.

Comment: Tables shouldn't be used.

Comment: ... and edited the title now to decline tables, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it just relying on the following properties: position, top, left, bottom and right so that to set up the right spots to allocate every tile in your grid.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>StackOverflow</title>
    <style>
:root {
    --tile-gap: 10px;
    --side: 70px;
}
.container {
    margin: 2px;
    padding: 20px;
    position: relative;
}
.orange-tile {
    background-color: orangered;
    width: calc( var(--side) + var(--side) + var(--tile-gap) );
    height: var(--side);
}
.gray-tile {
    background-color: gray;
    width: var(--side);
    height: var(--side);
}
.tile1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.tile2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: calc( var(--side) + var(--tile-gap));
}
.tile3 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: calc(  var(--side) * 2 + var(--tile-gap) * 2 );
}
.tile4 {
    position: absolute;
    top: calc( var(--side) + var(--tile-gap));
    left: 0;
}
.tile5 {
    position: absolute;
    top: calc( var(--side) + var(--tile-gap));
    left: calc(  var(--side) * 2  + var(--tile-gap) * 2 );
}

    </style>
</head>
<body>
<section class="container">
    <div class="gray-tile tile1"></div>
    <div class="gray-tile tile2"></div>
    <div class="gray-tile tile3"></div>
    <div class="orange-tile tile4"></div>
    <div class="gray-tile tile5"></div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```